# Can't find python pip on newly installed Buster on my old model B

Tags: python-3, raspbian-buster, pip, pi-b

Anyone else using python and pip on Buster lite?

Pip is not working for me on my old dual usb Model B. Just seems to be missing.

I tried installing it using the "get-pip.py" module from the official pip website but this just resulted in a long list of errors..!

In the end I downloaded Buster Desktop and this worked fine even though I only have access via ssh and so don't need the desktop.

So is it me and my old rpi or is there a problem with Buster-lite?

Comment: have you tried calling pip3 (since your question is tagged Python 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither a problem with Raspberry Pi model B nor a problem with Raspbian Buster Lite. Buster Lite only hasn't **pip3** available in its image but it is no problem to get it from its repository with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: I found it odd that pip wasn't on "Lite". I assumed it was only "lite" because it doesn't have a desktop. But at least I know now.